# C# Entity Framework 6: Out Of Memory when it absolutely should not run out of memory

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, out-of-memory

I've simplified things as much as possible. This is reading from a table that has around 3,000,000 rows. I want to create a Dictionary from some concatenated fields of the data.

Here's the code that, in my opinion, should never, ever throw an Out Of Memory Exception:

```
public int StupidFunction()
{
    var context = GetContext();
    int skip = 0;
    int take = 100000;
    var batch = context.VarsHG19.OrderBy(v => v.Id).Skip(skip).Take(take);
    while (batch.Any())
    {
        batch.ToList();
        skip += take;
        batch = context.VarsHG19.OrderBy(v => v.Id).Skip(skip).Take(take);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

In my opinion, the batch object should simply be replaced each iteration and the previous memory allocated for the previous batch object should be garbage collected. I would expect that the loop in this function should take a nearly static amount of memory. At the very worst, it should be bounded by the memory needs of one row * 100,000. The Max size of a row from this table is 540 bytes. I removed Navigation Properties from the edmx.

Comment: Entity Framework context will keep track of all the entities you've read from database to track for changes. Try recreating the context between iterations.

Comment: You can turn off tracking using `AsNoTracking`. Why not use a foreach loop though on a filtered IEnumerable<T> from the DbSet<T>? You can also help by only returning what you need using an anonymous type using `Select<T>()`

Comment: Thanks Igor. That makes perfect sense now. In the real code (this was just the WTF code to isolate the problem) I am iterating through the returned IQueryable in a foreach and adding values to a Dictionary. In the real code, ToList() isn't called. I just didn't realize the exception was being thrown by the change tracking in the context, rather than the ToList() of the result set.

Answer (score 2):

> You can turn off tracking using AsNoTracking. Why not use a foreach loop though on a filtered IEnumerable from the DbSet? You can also help by only returning what you need using an anonymous type using Select() – Igor

Thanks for the Answer Igor.

```
public int StupidFunction()
{
    var context = GetContext();
    int skip = 0;
    int take = 100000;
    var batch = context.VarsHG19.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(v => v.Id).Skip(skip).Take(take);
    while (batch.Any())
    {
        batch.ToList();
        skip += take;
        batch = context.VarsHG19.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(v => v.Id).Skip(skip).Take(take);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

No Out of Memory Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning the query's result to anything. How C# will understand what should be cleaned to assign new memory.

batch is a query and would not contain anything. Once you have called .ToList() this will execute the query and return the records.

```
 public int StupidFunction()
{
    var context = GetContext();
    int skip = 0;
    int take = 100000;
    var batch = context.VarsHG19.OrderBy(v => v.Id).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
    while (batch.Any())
    {

        skip += take;
        batch = context.VarsHG19.OrderBy(v => v.Id).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
    }

    return 1;
}
```